# Getting segmentation fault when reading a string in array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

I am working on implementing the Shunting Yard algorithm for a calculator project I am working on in C, and I am getting output I do not understand. My version of the algorithm is meant to take in an array of strings (the various tokens of the math expression, e.g { "40", "+", "7"}), and return the post-fix version of that expression -- {"40", "7", "+"}.

I've written some tests in Unity to test this algorithm, but I think I may be misunderstanding something about how arrays and strings work in C. I keep getting a segmentation fault whenever I try to read one of the strings in the input array. I have a feeling it has to do with how I am initializing them in the my tests. I'd appreciate any help I can get! Thank you.

Here is one of the tests:

```
void test_convert_addition(void)
{
  char *infix[] = {"40", "+", "7"};
  char *postfix[] = {"40", "7", "+"};
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING_ARRAY(postfix, to_postfix(infix, 3), 3);
}
```

And here is part of the implementation, ive included enough for to see up to when it fails.

```
char **to_postfix(char **infix, int length)
{
  int read_count = 0;
 
  char *current_token;

  while (read_count <= length)
  {

    current_token = infix[read_count++];
 // the following all result in seg faults
// printf("current_token: %s", current_token);
// printf("current_token[0]: %c, current_token[0];
   

// ...rest of code
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` should be `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: thank you -- what you say is also true, but even without that line I still get the error when I try to read that `current_token` string at all

Comment: Why does `is_in_group()` take a pointer as the first argument, not a character?

Comment: If you made that mistake, there may be other mistakes we don't know about. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I do hate to break it to you, but your code does not have anything to do with an array. (aside for the use in the *compound literal*) You are using pointers and pointers-to-pointers. You can use indexing as you would with an array to access a specific character or pointer, but keep the distinction between array and pointer and allocated block of memory clear in your head.

Comment: @Barmar updated with bare reproducible example, thank you

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for that. Am I misunderstanding then how I should be able to get a particular pointer in that pointer-to-pointer compound literal I initialized in my test? I would like to pass the pointer to the string `"40"` to another function, for example.

Comment: Your use of the compound literal is fine,. By initializing a pointer-to-pointer as an array-of-pointers the pointer arithmetic remains correct (e.g. `p + 1` is the address of the next pointer in either case). However, you lose all size information by doing it that way. Here it would be better to simply use an array-of-pointers (e.g. `char *infix[] = {"40", "+", "7"};` Up to you. In both cases `infix[0]` points to `"40"`, `infix[1]` to `"+"` and so on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that makes sense -- still getting the error whenever I try to actually read the `current_token`, but what you said is interesting

Comment: I suspect `while (read_count <= length)` should be `while (read_count < length)`, i.e. `read_count` should run from `0` to `length - 1`.  If it becomes `length`, you'll index past the end of `infix`, in which case `current_token` will be an invalid pointer, and dereferencing it may cause a seg fault.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's it, thank you! And thank you everybody else who helped out.